# How to store only unique data into Parse.com?

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

Am currently working on the android app which fetches data from a url. I need to save some info from it to parse. The data is saved when the user searches for something. So when the user searches the same thing it should be fetched from Parse Data browser.

Querying doesn't helped. Please give me a solution only to save new data and ignore existing data.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, please provide more information and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. I just queried for a particular term in the parse.com. Later if that object already exists, I just skipped saving the parse object. That's it.